# Using "Change Quantity on Checkout for WooCommerce" plugin without AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I decided to remove AJAX from the checkout page on my WooCommerce site, it works as expected and I'd like to keep it.

I have a plugin called "Change Quantity on Checkout for WooCommerce", it displays a plus and minus sign next to each product so the user can increase and decrease quantity on the checkout page instead of going back to the cart.

This plugin uses AJAX to change quantity, I would like to change it without using AJAX, by reloading the page on quantity change and update the quantity in the cart.

I know that there is an option to add a product from checkout page, like that:

`https://example.com/checkout?add-to-cart=426393`

I'm trying to find a URL parameter that changes quantity of a product just like that.

Maybe there is even an easier way to solve this problem, and I'd love to get some help.

Comment: I think you need to reprogram the plugin and do it with POST and GET variables. But all in all I think it's a bad idea disabling AJAX in WordPress since a lot works with AJAX - even WooCommerce itself.

Comment: just checkout page

Comment: There are a lot of things with AJAX on the checkout page. I'm not sure if it's worth the effort replacing everything. You need to check function for function I think. It's a long dev process. Which IDE do you use for programming? I would prefer Intellij which has a WordPress plugin - maybe this helps you finding all relationships.